# Blender 3d sphere material to 2d map

Tags: dictionary, 3d, png, blender

So I've been able to generate a 3d material for a sphere object in Blender. The material is based on the video found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dONehSMYEag&list=PL947FsytrZh9BnYzkb9X_-XIfihWYM4So&index=9) which uses a combination of nodes with the cycles renderer to generate a dynamic material. Although the finished product looks wonderful, I can't find a way to take this material and convert it to a png image. I'm not trying to render the image; I've already rendered an image of the object. I just want to take this generated planet and create a 2D map in the same way you might look at an image of the Earth that includes all surface area in one image.

Can someone help me create a png/jpeg of the 2D map or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is your question related to programming? (In some more direct way than "blender runs on a computer").

Comment: There's a possibility that the answer will require a coded solution. I have yet to find a way to handle this issue through the interface (though I could be missing something). Being a novice with this tool makes my answer your question uncertain.

Comment: A non-programming oriented solution: apply the texture to a sphere and then [unwrap](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6755/how-to-properly-unwrap-my-mesh) it? (Ah, there is a [blender.se] – your question surely is on-topic there!)

Comment: That may be part of the issue. I don't have an image that's being applied. Only nodes are being used to apply a colorized, shaded, and textured material output. Because I'm using the Cycles Render setting to generate the material, the normal unwrap method doesn't work.